# [Ruby on rails]Button who does a ruby action on click

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a beginner on ruby on rails (and web development). I'd like to make a system which sends a email to the webmaster when you click on the button.

I'm able to send a email when I click on a link
with `@announce.report(@announce.title)` in my html page, the report method is defined in announce.rb

I think I have to use javascript but i've no clue on how to add the ruby code `@announce.report(@announce.title)`in the button function. And I don't want to change url when I click on the button, but stays in the same page (which only shows a message after click "reported")

For the time being I've done that but it's not really what I want.

```
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Reported')">
```

I've looked into button_to and link_to but that's not what I want since I want to stay on the same page, just show a small message and does a ruby action after click.

Thanks a lot for help and good bye.

Comment: *And I don't want to change url when I click on the button, but stays in the same page (which only shows a message after click "reported"). I think I have to use javascript* --Yep.  Look at the jquery library's **ajax** family of functions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want an ajax(because you mentioned you don't want a page change) POST action like `send_mail` for your `link_to` helper. So that would mean adding `remote:true`, `method: POST` as options to it. Your serverside action(`send_mail`, or whatever you decide to name it) that handles the POST would then have prepare a message and hand it to Action mailer. Here is a basic manual to preparing simple examples with ActionMailer - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html.
I think you could then prep some unobtrusive javascript with a file like `send_mail.js.erb` in the same template directory as the current template, in order to provide an confirmation message, like `alert('Your Mail was sent!'), after it completes.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to send an ajax request to the server, rails has built in functions to do this for you.

You can do this in a link or a button:

```
<%= button_to "Send Email to Webmaster",
  url: { controller: "announce", action: "send_to_webmaster" }, remote: true %>
```

This will send a JS request to your `send_to_webmaster` action in your `AnnouncesController`. Setting `remote` to true will tell rails to stop its default behaviour and send a ajax request to your server (aka the built in function rails gives you).

Then you you can send an email the exact same way you did for your report method. Sending an ajax request will not change the page but rails will expect you to have a `send_to_webmaster.html.erb` or `send_to_webmaster.js.erb`, to mitigate this inconvenience rails gave us something else!

You can literally render nothing!
With:

`render nothing: true`